# Parsing a line in C with multiple spaces in the same filed

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I have a text file as follows:

```
id name area dist
1  surya kumar 1 2
```

when I try to parse this line in C using strtok() function with space as delimiter I'm getting the output as follows:

```
1
surya
Kumar
1
2
```

The second filed is actually a name so it can have multiple spaces in it. Is there a way to treat the second filed as a whole word and still be able to parse the entire line?

Comment: No, nothing standard. Howver, you can always check the next token to be non-numeric and consider that as a part of _name_ and move on. :)

Comment: How about just concatenating the second and third token (the first and last name) into a single string with a space between?

Comment: ...or a name could be three words, keep extracting tokens until field is numeric.

Comment: You'll have to write your own routine for this task. There's nothing standard. You could use regular expressions (e.g. PCRE library) though.

Comment: its a nice a idea to check for numeric but in my case some of the names are having numerics as a part of name e.g surya 15

Comment: It's a simple two step process: 1) Decide exactly what the rules are for determining where each field starts and ends. 2) Write code that implements the rules you decided on.

Comment: Another option is to pick some other delimiter for your file.  Tabs, for instance.

Comment: Another option is to replace the spaces in the names with underscores (`_`) and later remove them in the array by replacing the underscores with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your name may include numbers, I suggest counting the tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXFIELDS 10

int main(void) {
    //char input[] = "1 Ludwig 2 3";
    char input[] = "1 Ludwig 99 Beethoven 2 3";
    char *token[MAXFIELDS];
    char *tok;
    char name [100];
    int fields, index;
    int id, area, dist;

    fields = 0;
    tok = strtok(input, " ");
    while(tok != NULL) {
        if (fields >= MAXFIELDS)
            return 1;                           // error
        token[fields++] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    if (fields < 4)
        return 1;                               // error

    index = 0;
    id = atoi(token[index++]);                  // id field
    strcpy(name, token[index++]);               // name field
    while(index < fields - 2) {
        strcat(name, " ");                      // append to name
        strcat(name, token[index++]);
    }
    area = atoi(token[index++]);                // area field
    dist = atoi(token[index++]);                // dist field

    printf("%d, %s, %d, %d\n", id, name, area, dist);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
1, Ludwig 99 Beethoven, 2, 3
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling strtok, count the number of spaces in the string to know where the 3rd fields does start (i.e. where the second field does end).